# How do I specify the dispersion parameter when computing the confidence interval for a GLM?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, glm

I have a model of exponential decay in the form *Y = exp{a + bX + cW}*. In R, I represent this as a generalized linear model (GLM) using a gamma random component with log link function.

```r
fitted <- glm(Y ~ X + W, family=Gamma(link='log'))
```

I know from [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/240459/205187) that for the standard errors to really represent an exponential rather than gamma random component, I need to specify the dispersion parameter as being 1 when I call `summary`.

```r
summary(fitted, dispersion=1)
summary(fitted)  # not the same!
```

Now, I want to find the 95% confidence intervals for my estimates of *a, b, c*. However, there seems to be no way to specify the dispersion parameter for the `confint`, even though I know it should affect the confidence interval (because it affects the standard error).

```r
confint(fitted)
confint(fitted, dispersion=1)  # same as the last confint :(
```

So, in order to get the confidence intervals corresponding to an exponential rather than gamma random component, **how do I specify the dispersion parameter when computing the confidence interval for a GLM?**

Comment: why would you want to assume the dispersion to be 1? If you look at the confint, it is the mean +/- 1.96 * standard error. However, you are most likely violating the purpose of the gamma glm by setting dispersion to be 1

Comment: With a gamma glm, the model estimates the shape, meaning the variance is dispersion * mean. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247624/dispersion-parameter-for-gamma-family/247631#247631. If you set dispersion back to 1, you are basically ignoring the shape estimate. Isn't it easier if you use a log normal?

Comment: I voted to migrate the question to cross validated because this is more statistical in nature. I.e you can get a dispersion=1 confint estimate but it is most likely wrong statistically speaking

Comment: @StupidWolf As mentioned, my model is of exponential decay, so the random component should be the exponential distribution. Under the mean/shape parameterization of the gamma distribution, setting the dispersion (which is the reciprocal of the shape) will allow me to obtain SE and confint following my desired exponential distribution. I prefer the exponential distribution over gamma, because I am trying to model exponential decay, which I believe can be most reasonably assumed to follow the exponential distribution. Assuming it is gamma might be assuming too much.

Comment: ok.. sure but you fitted the model using a glm which minimizes the deviance according to a gamma distribution. Does a nls work for you? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/nls

Comment: @StupidWolf (2) I've explained my choice of model. If you're talking about taking the log of the response and fitting an OLM, that comes with assumptions I don't want to make: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/48679/205187

Comment: @StupidWolf (3) I posted my question here because it is about how to use an R function, confint, to work for my statistical approach. I would have posted to cross-validated if I had questions about the approach itself.

Comment: @StupidWolf (4) I'm not familiar with NLS, but I will take a look. Thank you!

Comment: @StupidWolf About fitting an exponential decay with gamma GLM: I don't believe the value of the MLEs themselves are affected by the value of the dispersion parameter. I don't have a strong stats background, but isn't the dispersion parameter is a multiplicative term independent of X in the exponential dispersion family, and so will not affect MLE estimation? This is also discussed in the link I posted in my question. However, the dispersion does affect the SE, confint, etc., which is the motivation for my question.